# Jitterbit: target CSV-file created with only header although "do not create emtpy files" is checked

Tags: csv, target, dataloader, jitterbit

In Jitterbit Dataloader 10.37 I want to create CSV-files from Salesforce data but only if the query returns data.
I checked "do not create empty files" on the target type local file but it is still creating a csv just with the header but with no data. I do not want files created with no data in it. It is not an option to not have the header at all in the files - I will need it when there is data from the query.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen in situations where the write operation is after a couple of other operations.  In that instance a header is written in the first operation, then another header is written in a second operation.  The first row is read as the header, the second row (another header) is read as data, and written out.

I always add in a condition where I check if one of the fields equals its name.  Something like this, to just skip those rows.

```
<trans>
  if(Id=="Id",
    false;,
    true;
  );
</trans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to send your output to a variable array. Then check the variable to see if data is present. So set your target to a global variable. Then add a script after that target and do your validation. To test your script use `DEBUGBREAK();`  to test and look at your variable content. That way you can see what is going into it.
Then make your condition statement.
if( Length($varailbe)>1,RunOperation("operation:myexport"),"novalue"):